# How to run these two heroku commands in a bash script?

Tags: bash, heroku

I'd like to run some heroku commands in a bash script. I know this is totally off and should take a course in bash, but the following is what I'd like to accomplish.

```
# get the database url and assign it to a variable
URL=heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a wt2-production

# insert the variable in another command
heroku pg:copy URL DATABASE_URL --app my-staging-app
```

How would I accomplish this in a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `$(command expansion)` and `"$variable_expansion"`:

```
# get the database url and assign it to a variable
URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a wt2-production)

# insert the variable in another command
heroku pg:copy "$URL" DATABASE_URL --app my-staging-app
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap that first command, in backticks to exec it & then use the $ to reference it in the next command:

```
# get the database url and assign it to a variable
URL=`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a wt2-production`

# insert the variable in another command
heroku pg:copy "$URL" DATABASE_URL --app my-staging-app
```